# Find Position of Objects in Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, coordinates, kineticjs

I'm dragging and dropping an image from a toolbar onto a canvas.The user can drag&drop that same image from the toolbar multiple times.The user can also remove a particular object on double click as shown in the link below..

http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/26/

I want to record the position of these objects on page load and also after moving them around in the canvas.For this i'm adding an event listener and a function which will show the positions of all the objects on button click

```
myButton.addEventListener('click', position);
```

The JS function used to calculate position of the objects..

```
function Rectangle(props) {
    var posX = this.posX = props.x;
    var posY = this.posY = props.y;

    this.width = props.width;
    this.height = props.height;
    this.fill = props.fill;
    this.isDragging = props.isDragging;

    this.draw = function() {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
        ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, this.width, this.height);

    }
}
```

Even though I'm adding the above JS function I'm not getting the output on button click..I don't know where i'm going wrong...Is there a simpler way of doing this in jQuery??

The link containing the above JS function

http://jsfiddle.net/gkefk/27/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take a few minutes to review what you've put together.**

Your top toolbar holds draggable DOM elements.

Once any draggable DOM element has been released on the Kinetic Canvas, you are creating a new Kinetic.Image at the same location as the dropped DOM element.  This Kinetic.Image cannot be accessed by jQuery because it is not a DOM element -- it is a Kinetic.Image node.

Therefore, you must access that new Kinetic.Image using KineticJS, not jQuery.

In your dragDrop, you give the Kinetic.Image a `name` property.  KineticJS `name` properties are like classes in Html/CSS.  This means if drag more than 1 image onto the canvas, you will have 2 images with the same `name`.  This is probably not what you intend.

Also, the `name` you are assigning each Kinetic.Image is "house.png" which you fetch from the drop element's "url" data property.  This is probably not what you intend.

Instead, if you assign each of your new Kinetic.Images a unique `id` property then you can use `stage.find` to get the specific Kinetic.Image with a specified `id`.  The Kinetic `id` property is like the Html/CSS `id` property.  Then you can get any desired Kinetic.Image's x,y,width,height like this:

```
var myDesiredKineticImage = stage.find("#"+myDesiredId);

var x=myDesiredKineticImage.x();
var y=myDesiredKineticImage.y();
var width=myDesiredKineticImage.width();
var height=myDesiredKineticImage.height());
```

Comment: Can you please give the link to the js fiddle containing the above code?

Comment: Oops! I forgot some parentheses in my example code--fixed now.  Anyway, I didn't do a fiddle because the concept is simple: (1) Assign each Kinetic.Image a unique `id`, (2) Get a reference to your desire image using `stage.find` and (3) Read that image's x,y,width,height properties. Cheers!

Comment: how will we find "myDesiredId"?? will it be different for different copies of the image inside the canvas? and where do i add the above code? inside the dragdrop() function or outside it?

Comment: Create a global variable `nextId`.  Inside dragdrop() assign `id:nextId++,`.  When you want the position/size of a particular image `var myDesiredKineticImage=stage.find("#"+myDesiredId)`. Then you can do myDesiredKineticImage.x() to get its "x" position.  But if you just want to get this info when the user drags a Kinetic.Image, you can listen for the `dragmove` event on each image and then get the dragging images's properties with `this.x()`, `this.y()`, `this.width()`, `this.height()` inside the dragmove handler. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/2UVLg/